# Why isn't this cron job restarting my docker containers?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cron

I currently have two docker containers running with the names `fe` and `be`, which I can see with `docker container list`, which gives the output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS             PORTS                                       NAMES
2f342ab21447   dockerimage1/blahblah  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp, :::80->3000/tcp       fe
12ea03925500   dockerimage2/blahblah    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:2053->3001/tcp, :::2053->3001/tcp   be
```

When I do `crontab -e` I can see my cron file:

```
# Jobs
10 2 * * * docker container restart fe && docker container restart be && echo 'Restarting Docker Container" > /root/clogs.txt
```

But it doesn't ever run, I tried checking the logs in syslog with `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` but i only see this repeated a bunch of times:

```
Feb  3 04:15:01 ubuntu CRON[106860]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb  3 04:16:01 ubuntu CRON[106869]: (user) CMD (/var/tmp/.update-logs/./History >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown)
```

I can tell that the cron job didn't work, because running `docker container list` again I can see that the status is still about an hour ago even when it was supposed to run 3 minutes ago.

Comment: First, creation time does not equal to uptime. Second, cron logs are sometimes stored in other files depending on the Linux distribution, maybe under /var/log/cron.d

Comment: You're right that creation time isn't uptime, which is why I referenced Status instead.